# Convert struct to cell or matrix?

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I have a struct array imported from a tab file, with 100+ name\double rows. The first row has a character value (name\char). I'm trying to load this as a matrix and converted it to cells, removing the top row entirely.

But when I use `cell2mat(array)`, it has the error:

> All contents of the input cell array must be of the same data type.

I know this is from the Names vs. double columns. But is there a way to convert this to a matrix? Or, if the data is rows of

```
name | 1000x1 double
```

is it better just to leave this as a cell array?

Comment: If I understand your description correctly, your data contains one row of names and the rest is numeric? Why not use the import tool (in MATLAB in the current folder viewer (side bar or tab) right click the data file and ‘Import data...’. There, you can easily exclude the first row and import the rest of the data as either named column vectors (names based on any row, e.g. the first), a matrix or whatever data type you want. When you click on the import data button, you can also generate a script or a function that will repeat this exact process for you, which can be very handy for more files.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to have a matrix containing both strings and numeric values. If you want something like that, cell array is your only option. But, it will be very limiting if you want to process the numeric values using matrix/vector operations, or functions that expect matrices/vectors as input. One option would be to store the strings and numeric data separately; keep the strings in a cell array `S` and the numeric data in a matrix `M`. Then, keep track of the elements. For example, `S{i}` and row `M(i, :)` could both correspond to entry `i` from your original table. Another option would be to make your own data structure using `struct()`, which can contain both strings and numeric values.

Comment: Thank you! That helps a ton especially in knowing how it is to analyze. I tried to use cell2mat(array) on an array of just the second column (with 1000x1 doubles; removing the names in 1st column). This concatenated all values to n x 1, though. How can I concatenate the rows in the cell array to create a matrix: 
[row 1 value]
[row 2 value]
etc.?

Comment: I did M=[array(2:125] *range was to remove the first line* , which seemed to work in the command line, showing the text of [1000x1 double] elements in one column. BUT when I look at the variable, it says it is a cell type variable.